# query fail getting data from multiple columns using WHERE clause in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, sqliteopenhelper

I've tried the following code to return multiple column values with where clause in android

```
public Cursor getData(String text) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{"Client","Action","Value","Period"};
    Cursor cr = db.query("phrase_table",columns,"phrase = ?",new String[]{text},null,null,null);
    return cr;
}
```

However, the cursor is returning only the "Client" column value. Here's the code for cursor to string:

```
Cursor c = vdb.getData(text);
    ArrayList<String> line= new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            line.add(c.getString(0));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    String resc="";
    for(String a:line){
        resc += a;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,resc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

tried this one too:

```
Cursor c = vdb.getData(text);
    String line = "";
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            line += c.getString(0);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    Toast.makeText(this,resc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: but in your code you are fetching data only from the `Client` column by providing 0 as index to `getString` call. Did you try other column indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching single data from cursor "Client", update your code for other

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
  do{
    line += c.getString(0);
    line += c.getString(1);
    line += c.getString(2);
    line += c.getString(3);
  }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked :) now that I think about it, it feels quite silly ^_^